# ModuleFederation, Angular test, jasmine: How to mock "loadRemoteModule"?

Tags: angular

Having this:

```
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {

    ...

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadRemoteComponent({
            componentName: 'testComponentName',
            exposedName: 'testExposedName',
            url: 'testUrl',
            params: {
                valueA: 'testParamsValueA',
                valueB: true
            });
    }
    
    private async loadRemoteComponent(config: AngularElementConfig) {
        const componentType = await loadRemoteModule({
            type: 'module',
            remoteEntry: config.url,
            exposedModule: config.exposedName
        })
            .then(m => {
                return m[config.componentName];
            }
            );
        ...
    }
}
```

Goal:
Angular test that covers the ".then(...)" code path.
"loadRemoteModule" should return a value like "{dummy : 123}" given in the Angular test.

Notice:
hundreds of of other tests are working fine.
So I guess the test setup is ok ;-)

Tryed:
(The following list should just provide the basic idea what i´ve already tried .. so please do not nail me when something is missing)

1. rewire
2. mockrewire
3. const spy = spyOn(loadRemoteModule as any, 'loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(returnValue));
4. const spy = spyOn(ModuleFederation, 'loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(returnValue));
5. const spy = spyOn(ModuleFederation as any, 'loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(returnValue);
6. export function loadRemoteModuleWrapper(options: any) {
   return loadRemoteModule(options);
   }

   let loadRemoteModuleWrapperSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(loadRemoteModuleWrapper as any, 'loadRemoteModuleWrapper');
7. 

```
const mockModuleFederation = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModuleFederation', ['loadRemoteModule']);
beforeEach(() => {
    (ModuleFederation as any).loadRemoteModule = mockModuleFederation.loadRemoteModule;
});

afterEach(() => {
    delete (ModuleFederation as any).loadRemoteModule;
});

mockModuleFederation.loadRemoteModule.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(returnValue));
```

8. 

```
const customLoader: any = (module: string) => {
    if (module === '@angular-architects/module-federation') {
        return {
            loadRemoteModule: jasmine.createSpy('loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({ willy: 123 })),
        };
    } else {
        return (window as any).require(module);
    }
};

const mockLoadRemoteModule = jasmine.createSpy('loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(returnValue));

(window as any).require = {
    '@angular-architects/module-federation': {
        loadRemoteModule: mockLoadRemoteModule,
    },
};
```

9. 

```
const ModuleFederation = rewire('@angular-architects/module-federation');
ModuleFederation.__set__('loadRemoteModule', jasmine.createSpy('loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(returnValue)));
```

10. 

```
const originalLoadRemoteModule = ModuleFederation.loadRemoteModule;
ModuleFederation.loadRemoteModule = jasmine.createSpy('loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(returnValue));
```

11. A lot of .keep, .mock, and .provide´s

beforeEach(() => {
return MockBuilder(TaskListComponent)
.keep(...)
.mock( ...)

})

Any ideas?
What do I miss?

UPDATE:
a)
Yes, some of these approaches are pure nonsense - so they show how desperate I am.

b)
All approaches are showing that the function "loadRemoteModule" is called and tryed to be worked out because at test run time I get always an error   saying that the requested remote module can not be loaded.
And this error would not occur in case the mock would work.

Update 2:
c)
See
https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/300

update 3:

13)

```
Object.defineProperty(require('@angular-architects/module-federation'), 'loadRemoteModule', { writable: true });

spyOn(require('@angular-architects/module-federation'), 'loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({ willy: 123 }));
```

Comment: What's wrong with `const spy= spyOn(loadRemoteModule, 'loadRemoteModule').and.returnValue(dummyValue)` ?

Comment: As of all my test approaches: The function "loadRemoteModule" is called and worked out!
So the test raise an error like "could not load remote module" which indicates that (as said) the method is called and the mock/spy does not work.

Comment: @VladimirRodchenko
No solution! no feedback, nothing, nada.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of how to unit test **loadRemoteModule**

First of all I want to say thank you to @manfredsteyer for his very fast response via email with detailed explanation of how it is better to unit test **loadRemoteModule**. After his message I was able to implement working unit tests.
Key idea of this solution is to create wrapper for **loadRemoteModule** instead of trying to mock it directly.

https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/300#issuecomment-1878415850

#### Create wrapper for loadRemoteModule

**module.federation.ts**

```
import { LoadRemoteModuleOptions, loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

export const ModuleFederationWrapper = {
  loadRemoteModule<T = any>(options: LoadRemoteModuleOptions): Promise<T>
  {
    return loadRemoteModule<T>(options);
  }
}
```

### Option 1

#### Using loadRemoteModule wrapper for Routes

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleFederationWrapper } from '../module.federation';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'news',
    loadChildren: () =>
      ModuleFederationWrapper.loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'manifest',
        remoteName: 'news',
        exposedModule: './Module'
      })
      .then(x => x.NewsModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

#### Unit tests

**app-routing.module.spec.ts**

```
import { Location } from "@angular/common";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { routes } from "./app-routing.module";
import { LoadRemoteModuleOptions } from "@angular-architects/module-federation";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { HeaderProxyComponent } from "./plugins/header-proxy/header-proxy.component";
import { ModuleFederationWrapper } from "../module.federation";

describe('AppRoutingModule', () => {

  describe('routes', () => {

    it('length should be one', () => {
      // Arrange & Act & Assert
      expect(routes.length).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('news', () => {
      // Arrange & Act
      let route = routes[0];

      // Assert
      expect(route.path).toBe('news');
    });
  });

  describe('routes: navigate', () => {
    let location: Location;
    let router: Router;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
      await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)],
        declarations: [
          AppComponent,
          HeaderProxyComponent
        ]
      })
      .compileComponents();
  
      router = TestBed.inject(Router);
      location = TestBed.inject(Location);
  
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      router.initialNavigation();
    });

    it('should load "news" module', async () => {
      // Arrange
      const loadRemoteModuleOptions: LoadRemoteModuleOptions = {
        type: 'manifest',
        remoteName: 'news',
        exposedModule: './Module'
      };

      const fakeModule: any = { };
      const remoteModule: any = {
        NewsModule: fakeModule
      };

      var mockLoadRemoteModule = spyOn(ModuleFederationWrapper, 'loadRemoteModule');
      mockLoadRemoteModule
        .withArgs(loadRemoteModuleOptions)
        .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(remoteModule));

      // Act
      const route = router.config.find(x => x.path === 'news');

      // Assert
      expect(await route?.loadChildren?.()).toBe(fakeModule);
    });
  });
});
```

### Option 2

#### Using loadRemoteModule wrapper when programmatic component loading

https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/module-federation-with-angulars-standalone-components/

**header-proxy.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ComponentRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ModuleFederationWrapper } from '../../../module.federation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-proxy',
  templateUrl: './header-proxy.component.html'
})
export class HeaderProxyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  title!: string;

  @ViewChild('placeHolder', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  viewContainer!: ViewContainerRef;

  component!: ComponentRef<unknown>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    (async () => {
      await this.loadHeader();
    })();
  }

  async loadHeader(): Promise<void> {
    const remoteModule = await ModuleFederationWrapper.loadRemoteModule({
      type: 'manifest',
      remoteName: 'header',
      exposedModule: './HeaderComponent'
    });

    this.component = this.viewContainer.createComponent(remoteModule.HeaderComponent);
    this.component.setInput('title', this.title);
  }

}
```

#### Unit tests

**header-proxy.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { LoadRemoteModuleOptions } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';
import { ModuleFederationWrapper } from '../../../module.federation';
import { HeaderProxyComponent } from "./header-proxy.component";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fake',
  template: '<p>Fake Component</p>'
})
class FakeComponent { }

describe('HeaderProxyComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderProxyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderProxyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        HeaderProxyComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderProxyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    // Arrange & Act & Assert
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('ngOnInit()', () => {

    it('should call "loadHeader()"', () => {
      // Arrange
      const mockLoadHeader = spyOn(component, 'loadHeader');

      // Act
      component.ngOnInit();

      // Arrange & Act & Assert
      expect(mockLoadHeader).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });

  describe('loadHeader()', () => {

    it('should loadRemoteModule', async () => {
      // Arrange
      fixture.detectChanges();

      const loadRemoteModuleOptions: LoadRemoteModuleOptions = {
        type: 'manifest',
        remoteName: 'header',
        exposedModule: './HeaderComponent'
      }

      const fakeComponentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(FakeComponent);

      const remoteModule: any = {
        HeaderComponent: fakeComponentFixture.componentInstance
      };

      var mockLoadRemoteModule = spyOn(ModuleFederationWrapper, 'loadRemoteModule');
      mockLoadRemoteModule
        .withArgs(loadRemoteModuleOptions)
        .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(remoteModule));

      let mockCreateComponent = spyOn(component.viewContainer, 'createComponent');
      mockCreateComponent
        .withArgs(remoteModule.HeaderComponent)
        .and.returnValue(fakeComponentFixture.componentRef);

      let mockSetInput = spyOn(fakeComponentFixture.componentRef, 'setInput');

      // Act
      await component.loadHeader();

      // Assert
      expect(mockLoadRemoteModule).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(jasmine.objectContaining(loadRemoteModuleOptions));
      expect(mockCreateComponent).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(jasmine.objectContaining(remoteModule.HeaderComponent));
      expect(mockSetInput).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(jasmine.stringMatching('title'), component.title);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Cool and thanks for your feedback!
Unfortunately, I no longer work for the company where I would have needed it.
But as I said, thanks for sharing.